# React mqtt subscription setState warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mqtt

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt with React. In my component I have:

```
componentDidMount:function(){

        client.subscribe('test/topic');
        client.on('message',function(topic,message){

            if(topic==='test/topic'){
                console.log(message.toString());
                this.setState({value:parseInt(message.toString())});


            }
        }.bind(this));

    },
componentWillUnmount:function(){
        client.unsubscribe('test/topic');
    },
```

So I subscribe to the topic when component will mount and unsubscribe when it unmounts. However, when i go to another view in my app and come back i get a warning with every mqtt message:

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component.
This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component.
This is a no-op.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues at one point. I have since moved back to the older `useEffect` syntax for my socket listeners and I don't seem to get those warnings now. Not certain that this is the fix but hopefully it helps!

```
useEffect(() => {
    client.on('message' () => {
        // update state
    }
    client.on('disconnect', () => {
        // update state
    }
})
```

Comment: Sorry - I've only just noticed the age of this question! Probably no longer relevant but hope it helps anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The callback function is getting called when the didMount method is declared. Move the callback into its own method. You won't need to bind `this`, either.

Comment: Doesn't help. I refactored all my classes to ES6, moved the callback into it's own function and I'm still getting this warning.